# How can I prevent Bootstrap from overriding my custom navbar?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf, navbar

I have a navbar and when i added bootstrap to my html pages navbar doesnt work anymore.I think that bootstrap is overriding my custom css.
Here my navbar:

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  !important;
  background-color: #333;
  !important;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  !important;
  color: white;
  !important;
  text-align: center;
  !important;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  !important;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  !important;
}

.logout {
  float: right;
  !important;
  horiz-align: right;
  !important;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  !important;
  border: none;
  !important;
  outline: none;
  !important;
  color: white;
  !important;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  !important;
  background-color: inherit;
  !important;
  font-family: inherit;
  !important;
  margin: 0;
  !important;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
  !important;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  !important;
  position: absolute;
  !important;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  !important;
  min-width: 160px;
  !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  !important;
  z-index: 1;
  !important;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  !important;
  color: black;
  !important;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  !important;
  display: block;
  !important;
  text-align: left;
  !important;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  !important;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  !important;
}
```

```html
<div th:fragment="header">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="logout">
      <a th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Hackathon
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a th:href="@{/administrator/search/hackathons}">Search</a>
        <a th:href="@{/administrator/create/hackathon}">Add</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Judge
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a th:href="@{/administrator/search/judges}">Search</a>
        <a th:href="@{/administrator/create/judge}">Add</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Mentor
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a th:href="@{/administrator/search/mentors}">Search</a>
        <a th:href="@{/administrator/create/mentor}">Add</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Team
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a th:href="@{/administrator/search/teams}">Search</a>
        <a th:href="@{/administrator/create/team}">Add</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Member
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a th:href="@{/administrator/search/members}">Search</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymleaf.org" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hackathon</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/style/header.css}">
  <link th:rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0-2/css/bootstrap.min.css} "/>
  <script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js}"></script>
  <script th:src="@{/webjars/popper.js/1.12.9-1/umd/popper.min.js}"></script>
  <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0-2/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>

</head>
```

Is there any way to keep this navbar? I tried to rename like this: ***class="navbar_custom"*** in html and css but its not working.I couldnt find some other navbar like this so i want it.I also tried this ***!important*** tag even i read that is not a good idea but still its not working.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason you're not converting it to a Bootstrap navbar, styled as you like? That would probably be less work and would leave you with something more standard and maintainable.

Comment: Your demo doesn't really show the situation. Are you loading your CSS _after_ Bootstrap? Please update your snippet to actually show the problem.

Comment: If an answer helped you, then please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `!important` on the same line.

But really what you should do is to adapt to the situation, use a proper Bootstrap navbar and style that as you want.

Another thing is, you have your `header.css` before the bootstrap css. If you put it after, it will come later in the cascade and you wouldn't need to use `!important`.

```
<link th:rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0-2/css/bootstrap.min.css} "/>
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/style/header.css}">
```

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  background-color: #333 !important;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  color: white !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  padding: 14px 16px !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

.logout {
  float: right !important;
  horiz-align: right !important;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px !important;
  border: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
  color: white !important;
  padding: 14px 16px !important;
  background-color: inherit !important;
  font-family: inherit !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  background-color: #f9f9f9 !important;
  min-width: 160px !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) !important;
  z-index: 1 !important;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none !important;
  color: black !important;
  padding: 12px 16px !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  display: block !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd !important;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div th:fragment="header">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="logout">
      <a th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Hackathon
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a th:href="@{/administrator/search/hackathons}">Search</a>
        <a th:href="@{/administrator/create/hackathon}">Add</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Judge
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a th:href="@{/administrator/search/judges}">Search</a>
        <a th:href="@{/administrator/create/judge}">Add</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Mentor
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a th:href="@{/administrator/search/mentors}">Search</a>
        <a th:href="@{/administrator/create/mentor}">Add</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Team
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a th:href="@{/administrator/search/teams}">Search</a>
        <a th:href="@{/administrator/create/team}">Add</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Member
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a th:href="@{/administrator/search/members}">Search</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. `!important` is problematic for long-term development and should be a last resort. There are better ways.

Comment: Also, we don't even know what the actual problem is yet. It could be missing class overrides in the custom file.